# Let $(G,*)$ be a group and $a,b \in G$, $|a|=n$ and $|b|=n$, and also $a*b=b*a$. Prove that $|a*b|=n$.

Tags: group-theory

Let $(G,*)$ be a group and $a,b \in G$, $|a|=n$ and $|b|=n$, and also $a*b=b*a$. Prove that $|a*b|=n$.

The way I approached this was that first I showed $(a*b)^n = e$ and assumed that $|a*b|=k, k<n$ but im failing to show the contradiction. I know that $|G|=n*p=k*q; p, q \in Z$, and also that $k$ divides $n$, but besides that im not sure which way to go.

Comment: It is not necessarily true that $|a * b| = n$ (in general, all we know is $|a*b|$ divides $n$).  Are you missing some assumptions?  Or perhaps there's a typo?

Comment: For example, consider $G=\mathbb Z/6\mathbb Z, *=$addition, $a=[1],$ and $b=[5]$. And this is not [tag:linear-algebra]

Comment: No actually this is a homework problem starting with "Prove ...". The teacher always starts with "Prove or disprove ..." if the given statement might not be true so now im really shocked, I didn't even think of trying to find a counterexample.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not true in general. For example, suppose $a \ne e$ has order $n > 1$. Then so does $a^{-1}$, since clearly $(a^{-1})^n = a^{-n}$ is the inverse of $a^n = e$ so is the identity, and suppose $(a^{-1})^d$ was the identity for $0 < d < n$. Then this would imply that $a^d = e$ a contradiction since $a$ has order $n$. So now we can take $b = a^{-1}$. Then $ab = e = ba$ does not have order $n$ since $n > 1$.

Comment: "And if $(a^{-1})^d$ was the identity for $0 < d < n$ then this would imply that $a^d = e$ a contradiction." What about deleting this sentance? It seems no help for the answer.

Comment: I'm just showing that $a^{-1}$ has the same order as $a$ for completeness

Comment: But you didn't use this, then why put it here?

Comment: I did, since the $b$ in the question needed to have the same order as $a$.

Comment: I mean it didn't lead to a contradiction, why do you put it here?

Answer (score 2):

Let $b=a^{-1}\neq e$.

The smallest counterexample (with $a\neq b$) is in $G=\Bbb Z_3$. Let $a\in G$ be nontrivial. Then $|a|=3$ and $\left|a^{-1}\right|=3$, but

$$\left|aa^{-1}\right|=|e|=1\neq 3.$$